# ios autolyouts: labels centering

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

In my app, I have two `UILabels` that can contain different length text inside, depends on selected localization. I want to center both labels to the `superview's` horizontal center.

For example: `|  "xxxxx""xxxx"  |`  for english it centered to `view` X. in another case it could be `| "xxxxxxxxxxxx""xxxx" |` or
`|  "xxxxxx""xxxxxxxxxx" |`. How do I make both labels centered to `superview` X. I'm receiving following results `|_______"xxxxxxxx""xxxxx..."|`  or
`|"xxxxxx"________"xxxxx"|`. I want to always center the labels based on their text length size. How I can do that in IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use subString and only one label???
Hehe, it's very simple...

If folow your idea, i thinks:

1. Set properties uilabel is fitsize
2. Set autolayout horizol spacing between 2 label is 0
3. Cacutator the total width (2 label) and width's parentView

   a = parentView.frame.size.width - (lbl1.frame.size.width+lbl2.frame.size.width)
4. Set autolayout lbl1: leading space in container = a/2
5. Set autolayout lbl2: trailing space in container = a/2

Comment: Thanks, so that means that I can't to do it in IB and should add some code to handle it.I was thinking that it's a very simple and common case and can be resolved in IB using only autolayouts

Comment: Yes, if you have only 1 label -> it's easy, you set label text in center and set layout for your label.
Else you have 2 label -> you need caculator x point to set layout for this. Keke

Answer (score 1):

You can add `UIView` as a container view of two UILabels.
Add two UILabels in this container view, then add spacing between left UILabel and right UILabel. Then add horizontal center to the container view.
Hope this will help!

Comment: yes, I was thinking about that. but in this case container view should fit the size label1.length +  label2.length and I don't know how to do that. is it possible with autolayouts to setup equal width for this case label1.width+  label2.width == container.width?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (but not always possible) is to join this two labels into one which is built with two strings and just center this label. If it's not possible to join these strings - use @SFF's solution